# Why are the radios not being checked every time I click the buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, attributes, radio-button

The radios will be checked by the buttons only 1 time by each buttons, I want them to be checked every time I click the buttons

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var radio = $(this).parent().attr("for");
    $("#" + radio).attr("checked", "checked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio4">

<label for="radio1"><button>Games1</button></label>
<label for="radio2"><button>Games2</button></label>
<label for="radio3"><button>Games3</button></label>
<label for="radio4"><button>Games4</button></label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prop()` to set the `checked` state instead of putting the same attribute on them all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var radio = $(this).parent().attr("for");
    $("#" + radio).prop("checked", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio4">

<label for="radio1"><button>Games1</button></label>
<label for="radio2"><button>Games2</button></label>
<label for="radio3"><button>Games3</button></label>
<label for="radio4"><button>Games4</button></label>
```